# How to optimally set spark driver properties in YARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying out various options for setting spark driver memory in yarn.

**Use Case:**

I have a spark cluster with 1 master and 2 slaves

```
master : r5d xlarge - 8 vcore, 32GB
slave  : r5d xlarge - 8 vcore, 32GB
```

I am using Apache Zeppelin to run the queries on spark cluster. Spark interpreter is configured with properties provided by Zeppelin. I am using spark **2.3.1** running on **YARN**. I want to create 4 interpreters so that 4 users can parallelly use this cluster.

**Config 1:**

```
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.driver.cores  7
spark.driver.memory 24G
spark.driver.memoryOverhead 3072M
spark.executor.cores    1
spark.executor.memory   3G
spark.executor.memoryOverhead   512M
spark.yarn.am.cores 1
spark.yarn.am.memory    3G
spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead    512M
```

*Below is the spark executor UI:*

[image]

**Config 2:**

```
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.driver.cores  7
spark.driver.memory 12G
spark.driver.memoryOverhead 3072M
spark.executor.cores    1
spark.executor.memory   3G
spark.executor.memoryOverhead   512M
spark.yarn.am.cores 1
spark.yarn.am.memory    3G
spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead    512M
```

*Below is the spark executor UI:*

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why is the container size of driver 0?
2. Is the spark.memory.fraction calculated as (spark.driver.memory-300)*0.6 ? If so, why is it not exact ?  (14.22, 7.02 resp)
3. Why is the container size of executor 3.8 GB ? According to my configuration, it should be 3G + 512M = 3.5 GB. This issue was not there with spark 2.1
4. No of VCores available to YARN is 8 per node. How is this possible since AWS gives vCPU with their instances? Hence I should only be getting 4 VCores according to AWS.
   https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/r5/
5. If I want to use 4 interpreters, should I distribute 32 GB of master equally to all the interpreters?

**Driver:**

```
spark.driver.cores  2
spark.driver.memory 7G
spark.driver.memoryOverhead 1024M
```